# SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow - remove characters from string variable

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm creating a SharePoint 2013 Workflow in SharePoint Designer (using SharePoint Online). 
How can I remove 2 last characters of a string workflow variable? 
Is there a way to do it for example using actions?

Answer (score 1):

Download SharePoint Designer Workflow String Actions WSP from here: http://spdwfstringactions.codeplex.com/
I saved the file in c:\deploy\

To deploy this solution, run SharePoint Management Shell as Administrator:

```
> Add-SPSolution c:\deploy\<solution file>.wsp

> Install-SPSolution -Identity SPWorkflowStringActions.wsp -GACDeployment
```

Make sure SPDWorkflowStringActions assembly is in C:\Windows\assembly.

Open SharePoint Designer. Now in workflow actions you will have a String Actions group that you can you for string manipulations. I hope it'll help!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SPD 2013, you can use the Utiliy Actions from the Action menu and select one of the method that fits your need.

I hope this help...